# Does chanting Hare Krushna mantra means that one is looking for moksha?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, mantras, bhakti

What if one devotee chants Hare Krushna Mantra and don't want to attain moksha, will lord attract him towards it and try to take away his material desires? Does chanting mantra means that one is looking for moksha? If yes, what is the alternate way to feel close to Krishna?

Answer (score 1):

ISKCON members are Gaudiya Vaisnavas, and Chaitanya Mahaprabhu added a new teaching that rendering pure devotional service to Krishna is more important than moksha. In fact, gaudiya vaisnavas are indifferent either to liberation or non-liberation, all they aspire to is krishna-prema-bhakti.

They cite Damodarashtakam, said to be in Padma Purana:

http://kksongs.org/songs/n/namamisvaram.html

Damodarastakam

> 4. O Lord, although You are able to give all kinds of benedictions, I do not pray to You for the boon of impersonal liberation, nor the highest liberation of eternal life in Vaikuntha, nor any other boon (which may be obtained by executing the nine processes of bhakti). O Lord, I simply wish that this form of Yours as Bala Gopala in Vrndavana may ever be manifest in my heart, for what is the use to me of any other boon besides this?

> 5. O Lord, Your lotus face, which is encircled by locks of soft black hair tinged with red, is kissed again and again by mother Yasoda, and Your lips are reddish like the bimba fruit. May this beautiful vision of Your lotus face be ever manifest in my heart. Thousands and thousands of other benedictions are of no use to me.

> 7. O Lord Damodara, just as the two sons of Kuvera, Manigriva and Nalakuvara, were delivered from the curse of Narada and made into great devotees by You in Your form as a baby tied with rope to a wooden grinding mortar, in the same way, please give to me Your own prema-bhakti. I only long for this and have no desire for any kind of liberation.